# std::chrono::from_stream correct usage

Tags: c++, std, c++-chrono, c++20

I am thinking about usage of function [`std::chrono::from_stream (std::chrono::year_month_day)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day/from_stream) to get [`std::chrono::year_month_day`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day/year_month_day) object from `const std::string&` like `2018-12-09T00:00:00`.

In cppreference is no example of usage `std::chrono::from_stream`. So I thought, that it could be used in the same way like [`std::get_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time).

But there is a catch. `std::chrono::year_month_day` has really wierd parameters (personal opinion)

```
(std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& is, const CharT* fmt, std::chrono::year_month_day& ymd, std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Alloc>* abbrev = nullptr, std::chrono::minutes* offset = nullptr)
```

and return for unknown reason `std::basic_istream`, so I realized that I really don't know, how to correctly use it.

Does anyone knows please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not so weird.

```
const std::string in = "2018-12-09T00:00:00";
std::stringstream ss(in);

std::chrono::year_month_day ymd;

if (std::chrono::from_stream(ss, "%FT%T", ymd))
{
    std::cout << "Date: " << ymd << '\n';
}
```

*(Sadly we cannot [demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3af2a370271d9835) this yet, as libstd++ [doesn't implement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) [P0355](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0355r7.html), and [libc++'s nascent support is insufficient](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bee7fc6db9e2279d).)*

Note that this *only* provides the year/month/day, so the time must be discarded.

You may wish to consider some of the other `from_stream` overloads (like maybe [this one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/utc_clock/from_stream)).

Comment: Oh, I understand know, why it returns basic_istream.

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný Yep just like the insertion/extraction operators you're used to

Answer (score 6):

First, `from_stream` works on streams, not strings. If you want to use a string, you have to go through a stream first:

```
std::istringstream iss("2018-12-09T00:00:00");
```

Now the function you were expecting is actually [parse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/parse), not `from_stream`. It works like other manipulators such as `get_time`, and delegates its work to `from_stream`:

```
std::chrono::year_month_day date;
if (not (iss >> std::chrono::parse("%FT%T", date))) {
    // Handle error
}
```

This is equivalent to `from_stream(iss, "%FT%T", date)`.

You can see some usage of parsing in [Howard's CppCon talk on time zones](https://youtu.be/Vwd3pduVGKY?t=1344). He goes on to show examples that use the extra parameters to determine which time zone abbreviation and offset were actually parsed, but this is not relevant to the use case in your question. (Howard is the author of the library on which this was based, as well as the person who pushed for its standardization.)