# How can I convert the day of the year (365 days) equivalent date December 31

Tags: c++, time, mktime

how can i use the c++ library such as mktime() to convert day to dates instead of making my own algorithm

Comment: I'm fairly certain that all years have at least 365 days.

Comment: In C++ use [<chrono>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) also see: 
[chrono from_stream correct usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276105/stdchronofrom-stream-correct-usage).  Note : If  you have to include a header file from C++ with `.h` in it you are including a header file that's (usually) there for backward compatibility with "C".

Comment: @PepijnKramer   .... or a header for backward compatibility to pre-standard C++.   For example, `<iostream>` first appeared in a draft C++ standard in 1996, and `<iostream.h>` was routinely used in C++ from 1990 through to early 2000s (since it took a while for implementations to catch up and fully support the standard after it was first ratified in 1998).

Comment: @Peter nice addition and true. I should have know, used C++ since 1995. ;) (But I also haven't used any .h files from the standard library for a long long time now)

Comment: Another good option would be to use Howard Hinnant's date/time library : https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date. (Specialy if you can't use C++20 yet)

Answer (score 1):

Mktime is not C++, but a C library function. And honestly, it's pretty terrible. The fact that you're even mentioning it might point to you reading outdated material. Also, it's serving a different purpose than what to seem to think it does, but that is of no consequence here:

So, a modern C++ solution (all credits to [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75217109/how-can-i-convert-the-day-of-the-year-2017-365-days-equivalent-date-december/75217149#comment132728905_75217149), who [put this code on godbolt compiler explorer, which I reworked a bit](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4jKo9xP7T) for you to experiment with:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::literals;
namespace chr = std::chrono;

int main() {
    constexpr auto day_of_year = 365;

    // y suffix, to turn 2022 into a year specification in std::literals
    // the overloaded / operator makes specifying Gregorian calendar dates easy
    const auto date = chr::sys_days{2022y / 1 / 0} + chr::days{day_of_year};

    // Year-month-day representation of the resulting date
    const chr::year_month_day ymd(date);

    // Weekday
    const chr::weekday day_of_week(date);
    constexpr std::array<const char*, 7> weekdays{"Weekend, the 2nd",
                                                  "Extended Weekend",
                                                  "Tuesday",
                                                  "Funday",
                                                  "Ultimate Funday",
                                                  "Pre-Weekend",
                                                  "Weekend (first day)"};

    // explicitly cast to int (for years, which exist BC) or unsigned
    // (month of year and day of month are always non-negative)
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(ymd.year()) << "-"
              << static_cast<unsigned>(ymd.month()) << "-"
              << static_cast<unsigned>(ymd.day()) << ",\n"
              << "Which is a " << weekdays[day_of_week.c_encoding()] << "\n";

    // note that the above date calculation is all based on constants, so the
    // compiler does it for you at compile time – it doesn't get more efficient
}
```

C++ has `std::chrono`. And that allows you to do something like create a date-representing object that describes the beginning of a year, and then add a time delta, i.e., a `std::duration` (e.g. 365 days or 10⁶ seconds) to it, then convert it to whatever readable representation you need.

You should have actually stumbled across it! Documentation is [ample and readily available](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Comment: You beat me to an answer, but to save you the trouble: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1dd66Trr9. Looks like godbolt's having an issue, but It Works On My Machine™.

Comment: Is the output really 2022-12-31?  I'm thinking you've got an off-by-1 error and your output is 2023-01-01.  But you're really close to what I would've written: `sys_days{year/1/0}`.  One data point for "invalid dates" for the win! ;-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant, I'm dumb and forgot I changed that to /0 in my local IDE, so I didn't copy it back into godbolt. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: [std::mktime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) is part of the [C++ standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/time#ctime.syn). Your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @chris worked your code down to "works on godbolt as well", and reduced C++ std to C++20. Thanks!

Comment: @NoleKsum that's true, but I'd call a library that's literally specified to *literally* be *identical* to the C library's API not C++. It's C. *The contents of the header `<ctime>` are the same as the C standard library header `<time.h>`*. From a practical point of view, that's why your answer looks (no criticism, it comes with using `<ctime>`) like someone tries to rescue one of the lesser beautiful libc libraries to C++.

Comment: @MarcusMüller are you aware that except for a couple of libraries, *everything* in the C++ standard library sits on top of the standard C library? Basically the entire C++ standard library is just a very thin shell on top of the workhorse C library. Look at any server and +80% of the packages are all written in C while only about 1-2% in C++. [Check this out](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/chrono.cc#L59) or [this](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/futex.cc#L166)

Comment: That's not 100% true, but in principle, I'm aware of what you mean. That doesn't make any code that uses C-heritage libraries read very "C++-y", at all; there's a lot of things that you *can* do in C++ that you don't, and there's specifically things coming from the C that just don't fit into the C++ data models. A very strong candidate for that is having to `(std::)memset` a `struct`; that's just not … right for a RAII-oriented language. Which is why I'm happy to say that with `std::chrono`, there's very little reason to burden oneself with the bad design that `time.h` was for ~50 years.

Comment: I mean, the good thing is: C++ allows you to use a construct that's C, and at that, predates even C89. It doesn't *force* you to write well-readable code, either! But: If you get the choice, writing C89 in a C++ program is probably not the appropriate choice, especially for a beginner.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You have to realize that the two comments above are just **your** style of coding, nothing more.  It is insane to advertise it as a universal truth.  `std::mktime` is part of the C++ standard, period. It is there for a reason.

Comment: @NoleKsum Hm, they're an opinion, definitely! Consider the fact that the usually very slow C++ consortium, in which big companies with needs for robust C++ programs and sensible implementaiton, standardized `std::chrono`. Again, an opinion, but that did not happen because `<ctime>` fits into C++ but could be feature-richer. In my experience, `<ctime>` is an anachronism (haha, a pun!) and the fact that it's nothing to do with RAII, doesn't allow for compile-time determinism and leads to syntaxes far from what a C++ programmer should write in a usual context demonstrates that very nicely.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Fair. But consider how many people have been jumping boat from C++ because, in their own words, it has become overengineered and extremely complex to be rationally used in a production environment. Started with Stroustrup and Remember the Vasa, see how Rust is taking off, Sutter with CppFront, Karruth/Google with Carbon. Nobody wants to bash C++ but pretty much everyone recognizes that it has become quite unmanageable. C++ is becoming deadland because of this mentality.

Comment: @NoleKsum i.e., I **opine** that your code would be both measurably *better* (compiler can optimize it, and illegal operations can be caught at compile time, even if my example doesn't make use of that) and nicer to read if it didn't use the C-ism `mktime` from the legacy `ctime` library, and instead went with a library that's actually a C++ library, and not a C library that made it into a long superseded C++ standard for lack of better alternatives.

Comment: Whether or not `std::chrono` is overengineered is a different question than whether `mktime` in C++ is a good idea! If you don't like C++, why are you writing it? Your answer could have been C from start to finish, but then you would have noticed you've not actually given a C++-ic answer, but C that just happens to be valid C++, as well.

Answer (score 0):

One example of how to use `std::mktime` to handle the proposed problem is written below.

The key to this algorithm is to use `std::mktime` to convert from the year input to a base year epoch, ie the number of seconds from 1970-01-01 until year-01-01.

Then you add manually the number of seconds until the date you want. Remember leap seconds do not count so just adding 86400, the number of seconds in a day, is correct.

The last step is to convert back from epoch time into a full date.

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

struct YearDay {
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};

YearDay convert( int year, int yday ) {
    // Convert year to epoch
    struct tm tms;
    std::memset(&tms,0,sizeof(tms));
    tms.tm_year = year - 1900;
    std::time_t date = std::mktime(&tms);

    // add days manually
    date += yday * 86400;

    // Synthesize into a full date
    struct tm* newtm = std::gmtime( &date );
    return YearDay{newtm->tm_year+1900, 
                   newtm->tm_mon+1, 
                   newtm->tm_mday};    
}
```

One example of usage would be:

```cpp
int main() {
    int year = 2022;
    for ( int yday = 1; yday<=365; ++yday ) {
    YearDay yd = convert( year, yday );
    printf( "%4d %-3d  ==> %4d-%02d-%02d\n",
            year, yday, yd.year, yd.month, yd.day  );
    }
}
```

Produces when run:

```
Program stdout
2022 1    ==> 2022-01-01
2022 2    ==> 2022-01-02
2022 3    ==> 2022-01-03
...
2022 363  ==> 2022-12-29
2022 364  ==> 2022-12-30
2022 365  ==> 2022-12-31
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/YvGsoenbK

Comment: For the interested reader of this answer: Nole and I have a rather interesting (I think!) discussion about this answer of his here, and my answer below my answer. My opinion is that this is all C code (maybe with `std::` put in front of it), which just happens to be valid C++, but not really something you would want to see in a C++  code base. Nole is, understandably, of a different opinion; I'd recommend reading both answers, and forming an opinion of your own!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, December 31 2022 was a Saturday, not a Sunday as your title suggests.

[image]

While you could probably find a std:: library way to get what you want, I ask smaller versions of the "compute the day of the year" type problems in interview loops. So it was rather easy for me to drop this code for you. Here's a function that will take a year and a "day of the year" (a value between 1-365 or 1-366 for leap years) and generate a string for the month, day, and day of week.  Enjoy.

The downside of this code is that the strings are hardcoded to English. But it works. If you need to make it work for dates before 301 AD, it will need a minor adjustment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string MakeDate(const int year, const int dayOfYear) {
    auto isLeapYear = [](int y) {
        return (y % 400 == 0) || ((y % 4 == 0) && (y % 100 != 0));
    };
    static const int days_in_month[13] =    { 0, 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 };
    static const int days_in_month_ly[13] = { 0, 31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 };
    static const string month_names[13] = { "", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
    static const string day_names[7] = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursay", "Friday", "Saturday" };

    // January 1, 301 was a Tuesday if the Gregorian calendar went back that far
    // Every 400 years since then, it's been a Tuesday on January 1
    // 0=Sunday, 1=Monday, 2=Tuesday.... 6=Saturday
    int firstDayOfYear = 2;
    int computeYear = 301;
    int diff = (year > computeYear) ? (year - computeYear) : 0;
    computeYear += 400 * (diff / 400);

    while (year > computeYear) {
        int addOn = isLeapYear(computeYear) ? 2 : 1;
        firstDayOfYear = (firstDayOfYear + addOn) % 7;
        computeYear++;
    }

    // assume "jan 1" is "dayOfYear==1". Normalize it to be a zero based offset
    int days = dayOfYear - 1;
    int d = 1;
    int m = 1;
    int y = year;
    int dayOfWeek = (firstDayOfYear + days) % 7;

    const int* dim = isLeapYear(y) ? days_in_month_ly : days_in_month;

    while (days >= dim[m]) {
        days -= dim[m];
        m++;
        if (m > 12) {
            m = 1;
            y++;
            dim = isLeapYear(y) ? days_in_month_ly : days_in_month;
        }
    }
    d = 1 + days;

    string result = month_names[m] + " " + to_string(d) + " " + to_string(y) + ", " + day_names[dayOfWeek];
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    // print out all 365 days of 2022
    for (int i = 1; i <= 365; i++)
    {
        std::cout << MakeDate(2022, i) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question was he to use the c++ standard library for this purpose